# suma alternativa con sql oracle o my sql

Tags: sql

Hola necesito sumar únicamente todos los que conforman o tiene cero 0 en el campo ordenada
solo necesito sumar el campo order que es el 132 donde ordenada tiene todo cero 0
y sumar el campo order 333 porque todos tienen cero 0 los demás 508 y 404 no necesariamente sumarlos, solo interesa sumar los 132 y 333 por tener cero 0 en todo el campo ordenada

| ORDER | ordenada | recibida | cancelada | costo |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 508 | 2 | null | 2 | 4 |
| 508 | 0 | null | 1 | 2 |
| 508 | 1 | 1 | null | 6 |
| 508 | 0 | null | 1 | 4 |
| 508 | 0 | null | 2 | 5 |
| 508 | 1 | 1 | null | 6 |
| 132 | 0 | null | 1 | 2 |
| 132 | 0 | null | 1 | 3 |
| 132 | 0 | null | 1 | 4 |
| 132 | 0 | null | 1 | 5 |
| 404 | 2 | 2 | 0 | 7 |
| 404 | 1 | 1 | null | 5 |
| 404 | 1 | 1 | null | 6 |
| 333 | 0 | null | 1 | 2 |
| 333 | 0 | null | 1 | 3 |
| 333 | 0 | null | 1 | 4 |
| 333 | 0 | null | 1 | 5 |

Podrían ayudarme por favor puede en sql oracle o en nysql la ayuda

---

la suma para 132 es 14
la suma para 333 también es 14
otro ejemplo
la suma para 555 es 18 solo sumar los que tiene todos cero 0 en la columna ORDENADA
Obviamente son 5 mil registros

555 0   null    1   2
555 0   null    3   1
555 0   null    1   7
555 0   null    3   6
555 0   null    1   1
555 0   null    2   1

Comment: Edita tu pregunta y pon lo que has intentado para que se te pueda ayudar

Comment: Podrías agregar un ejemplo del resultado esperado? ejemplo: `508 = 11`, `132 = 14`, `404 = 0`, `333 = 14`.

Comment: La explicación es muy poco clara. Sugiero agregar una explicación alternativa y, muy importante, el resultado esperado con los datos de ejemplo suministrados.

Comment: Mira [ask] para que tu pregunta sea mejor recibida. También, aprovecha y haz el [tour] para entender mejor cómo funcionamos y de paso obtener tu primera [medalla](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/badges)!

Comment: Pero.. que sql intentaste?? porque con un where y un group by sale solito.. por favor, aclaras que fue lo que probaste????

Answer (score 2):

Creo que esta consulta responde a tus requisitos y muestra el costo total agrupando por ORDERID solo de aquellas líneas correspondientes a una orden con todas las ORDENADAs a cero. Esta segunda parte se consigue con una clausula HAVING, si totalizamos también la columna ORDENADA, queremos quedarnos con aquellas ordenes para las que filtro sea 0

```
SELECT ORDERID, SUM(ORDENADA) AS FILTRO, SUM(COSTO) AS TOTAL
FROM PRODUCT 
GROUP BY ORDERID 
HAVING FILTRO = 0;
```

Con los datos que has puesto, el resultado obtenido ejecutando esa consulta es

| ORDERID | FILTRO | TOTAL |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 132 | 0 | 14 |
| 333 | 0 | 14 |

Puedes probar la consulta en MySQL en [este SQL FIDDLE](https://sqlfiddle.com/mysql/online-compiler?id=877bb387-4cbc-4fa2-9f5a-f15ad7ac2afd) y para Oracle [en este otro](https://dbfiddle.uk/RY_iiNag). En el futuro procura incluir en tu pregunta la definición de la tabla, los inserts necesarios para tener un juego de datos mínimos, la consulta que has realizado hasta ahora y el resultado esperado.

Comment: Este having no funcionaria en Oracle (que fue uno de los requisitos, y por eso la pregunta es tan pero tan mala...) sin embargo tu respuesta esta bien.

Comment: @gbianchi Ponía Oracle o MySql. :-) La pregunta no está muy bien definida, no

Comment: La pregunta es mala, semi abandonda, y te tomaste un monton de trabajo por alguien que no se, si va a volver a aceptarla.. pero si considero un error que no aclares que esto asi, solo funciona en mysql... ;)

Comment: @gbianchi Vale, no había entendido tu comentario como que me faltaba eso. Añadido.

Comment: @gbianchi He ejecutado la misma consulta en Oracle SQL 23c y funciona https://dbfiddle.uk/RY_iiNag

Comment: Muy interesante tu respuesta y muy buena también

Comment: @Japv Gracias! :-)

Comment: Ah mira vos.. pero es muy moderna.. tene en cuenta que la mayoria que tiene oracle, no llego a esa version todavia.. igual, siempre mejor escribirlas en ansi sql... para que funcione en todas... having sum(ordenada) = 0 hacia que funcione en absolutamente cualquier base...

Answer (score -2):

Para sumar únicamente los valores del campo "order" (orden) donde el campo "ordenada" (ordenada) tiene todos ceros (0), puedes utilizar una consulta SQL con una cláusula WHERE que filtre los registros apropiados. Aquí tienes cómo hacerlo tanto en Oracle como en MySQL:

En Oracle:

```
SELECT SUM(order) AS total
FROM tu_tabla
WHERE ordenada = 0
GROUP BY ordenada
HAVING COUNT(*) = SUM(CASE WHEN ordenada = 0 THEN 1 ELSE
```

En MySQL:

```
SELECT SUM(order) AS total
FROM tu_tabla
WHERE ordenada = 0
GROUP BY ordenada
HAVING COUNT(*) = SUM(IF(ordenada = 0, 1, 0));
```

Comment: no creo que quiera sumar order. tampoco entiendo el having... si agrupas por ordenada order es cualquier cosa.. supongo por el ejemplo que queria sumar costo, si y solo si, todos los valores de ordenada eran 0 para el mismo order.

Comment: en general es un ejemplo para que sustituya por sus valores, pero textualmente escribió "solo sumar los que tiene todos cero 0 en la columna ORDENADA"